# Making a custom mouse cursor in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, gnome, themes, cursor, cursor-theme

I have done some customization to my desktop but I am really stumped on trying to figure out how to make my own mouse cursor by taking a `png` and editing it and then making it an `x11` file.

I have gotten all the files I need and made them all, in fact the cursor (its a star trek logo) shows up in the gnome tools advanced setting as star-trek-cursor, but when I go into the command line to use `sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme`, it does not show up in the list anywhere to set it.

I have tried making a `.theme` file where all the other X11 cursors are located, but no luck so I figured I would see if anyone else out there has had luck with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cH1zij5yM9I) and [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VsPuXIhDV6g) video tutorial might help you making cursor theme.

To change cursor theme, Go to software center and install **Unity tweak tool**. Open it, select cursors and select the cursor that you like.

Comment: thanks for the reply, are you able to use this software to create a custom cursor?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure. There are several cursors you can choose. Try finding icons of these cursors in the folder when the program is installed and modifying them.

Comment: I did change my cursor to an oxy-viorange already, however I am determined to figure how to make my own cursor, I know there is a way I just need to find it. my only problem is that I am not sure how to get the file to show up in the terminal so I can set it

Comment: Try [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cH1zij5yM9I) and [this(part2)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VsPuXIhDV6g). If it works please mark this as answered.

Comment: Thanks I will try this when I get the time and I will get back to you

Comment: I was really close but the video helped thanx!!!

Comment: @DusanMilosevic This is not what OP asked. They asked how to make cursor theme and you answered how to select a cursor theme!

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command in a Terminal Window let me know if this helps :)

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme
```

(..) Choose the cursor number that you would like to use
(..) exit terminal
(..) log out
(..) log back in ;)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have tried running this command in the terminal but the mouse cursor I designed does not show up, I was trying to take an image and save it as a png and then use it for my cursor, I have the files for it all made, how ever I can not seem to find a way to choose the image file that I have created, it alows me to choose it as a cursor in my advanced settings but it will not show up in the terminal when I run the sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme command