# How do I change how the mouse pointer looks?

Tags: mouse

Can I install different styled mouse pointers? Like the Crystal Clear or DIM TechnoBlue mouse pointer from Windows. ex: http://theblueguy07.deviantart.com/art/DIM-v3-0-TechnoBlue-372932491 and http://theblueguy07.deviantart.com/art/Crystal-Clear-v3-1-298678459

Comment: Maybe this can help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/426735/making-a-custom-mouse-cursor-in-ubuntu-12-04

Answer (score 2):

download gnome and tweak tool then change cursor bindings.

To install type in terminal: `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`
then change the settings.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DiXd.png)

You can choose from some of the stock cursors or download new cursor packages and install them.

Comment: But how do I change the mouse pointer?