# Help find the mouse pointer

Tags: mouse-pointer

Is there a way to make the mouse pointer grow in size when I move it quickly when I cannot find it on screen so that I can find it easily.

I've seen this feature in MacOS and I would like to have it in Ubuntu.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/776011/how-do-i-change-how-the-mouse-pointer-looks